# Is there any way I can change css by clicking event without using state in react?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript

I'm making a chip component, and I want to make it reusable.
Since the state is not used in every component which uses this chip component, I don't want to use state and change the background color when it's clicked and un-clicked.

To explain in detail, I'm going to make Chip a common component and use it in various menus. Some of these menus may not use the click function when using them, so I want to prevent unnecessary use of state, and solve it just with CSS. In addition, it is important to change to another CSS when you click whether you recognize a click. Clicked action is different in each component which uses the Chip component.

How can I use it without using the react-hook state?

[Unclicked Chip example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrjY6.png)

[Clicked Chip example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZFci.png)

Comment: using dynamic classNames, `className={'${condition ? "first__styleClass" : "second__styleClass"}'}`

Comment: How would the component know if the chip component is clicked or unclicked?

Comment: The state should be specific to your reusable chip component, so you won't use that _outside_ of your chip component. Just use state, that is the preferred way. Or try to explain your concerns with a bit more detail.

Comment: To explain in detail, I'm going to make Chip a common component and use it in various menus. Some of these menus may not use the click function when using them, so I want to prevent unnecessary use of state, and solve it just with CSS.

Comment: In addition, it is important to change to another CSS when you click whether you recognize a click. Clicked action is different in each component which uses Chip component

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use the [CSS with a hidden checkbox](https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/) trick. It uses a hidden HTML checkbox that is toggled on and off when you click the component.

An alternative solution would be to make the component handle its own state (i.e. not dependent on the state of its parent component).